# Check which data is received by serial port with "IF" statement in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

> I am able to receive data from serial port, but i want to check which
>   data is received.

**Here is the code :**

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
   If int = 0 Then
     If SerialPort1.ReadExisting() = "a" Then
       'Do Something i want
     End If
   End If
```

> So, i used "ReadExisting()" funtion for receiving data. It allows me
>   receive data but, not let me check what data is received.
>
> "I want to check the received data and if data is received is same as
>   as 'Character - a' then have to do the task i want."
>
> Thanks in Advanced. :)

Comment: The odds that this code can work are very low.  You get whatever data happens to be present in the driver's receive buffer.  The odds that it is *exactly* one character are never good.  It depends on the *protocol*, you have to read the manual of the device to know how it formats the data it sends.  More typically, you'd for example use ReadLine() if the BytesToRead property is larger than 0.  Or use the DataReceived event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do really have to achieve it by polling receiving buffer , here's my suggested code to solve your question:

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
     If SerialPort1.BytesToRead > 0 Then
        'once anything have been received and stored in inner buffer.
         If SerialPort1.ReadChar() = "a" Then
               'Do Something you want
         End If
     End If
   End Sub
```

The concept is , check if there's anything existed in receiving buffer , if it was , read one char out. If the out char is valid , do your own actions.

By the way  , using **ByteToRead** to do pre-check could prevent your timer be blocked when calling **ReadChar** , if nothing be received on serial port.

Comment: This did not work with my code. I also used the ReadLine instead of character.